# Add css for the text in the table which is having children

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have a table header. which is like,

```
<th>Technology<i className="fa fa-angle-up sort-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i><i className="fa fa-angle-up sort-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
```

Now in this I want to add some margin right to Technology as both header and icon are appearing close to each other.

So, How can I add that selector ?

```
<div className="d-inline-flex flex-column">
      <i className="fa fa-angle-up sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type, 'ascending')}></i>
      <i className="fa fa-angle-down sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type, 'descending')}></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: add 'margin-left' on icon instead text.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple just put

```
.sort-icon{
    margin-left: 10px; // chnage the margin as per your requirement
}
```

hope this will solve your query.

Comment: if still have some query you can just ask me.

Comment: How about to that text onbly

Comment: @GaneshKaspate in case you just want to put margin to text , you just put the text in span and put the margin-right to the span

Comment: hope this will solve your query. if still have query just ask

Comment: actually my table data was not getting at center . I will put an image

Comment: SO in the image the icons are not coming proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189572/discussion-between-nitin-garg-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Answer (score 0):

```
.sort-icon {
    margin:5px;
}
```

This will gave margin to all four sides.